# Struct implementing interface function without boxing

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

#### Background

I want to allow a class instance to register callbacks with an event system while avoiding boxing.

A bit of background: I have a home-grown Event System structured as shown below:

```cs
class EventSystem
{
    // registers a struct instance with an event
    // when the event triggers, it calls the run() method and passes in some info
    public void Register(ICallback callbackStruct, Event e);
}

public enum Event
{
    SOME_EVENT,
    SOME_OTHER_EVENT
}

interface ICallback
{
   void Run(string data);
}
```

An example implementation of this is:

```cs
class Example
{
    private Behaviour_A a = new Behaviour_A();
    private Behaviour_B b = new Behaviour_B();

    public Example()
    {
        eventSystem.Register(a, SOME_EVENT);
        eventSystem.Register(b, SOME_OTHER_EVENT);
    }

    struct Behaviour_A : ICallback
    {
        void Run(string data)
        {
            // some behvaiour
        }
    }

    struct Behaviour_B : ICallback
    {
        void Run(string data)
        {
            // some other behvaiour
        }
    }

}
```

#### Pros

I like this solution because it makes use of composition rather than inheritance (and also supports multiple callback behaviours for the same event in one instance), and I'd prefer to use structs over anonymous functions since they are stateful and might be re-used with different parameters and a few other reasons.

#### Cons

However, I dislike this solution because it requires boxing each time the struct is passed around and I'm trying to avoid heap allocations as much as possible.

#### Question

Is there any way I can implement custom behaviouron a struct as shown while avoiding boxing?

Comment: You could use delegates for the callbacks? That way a class can implement multiple private functions for the callback implementations, then assign them to a delegate variable for your `EventSystem` to track.

Comment: It depends on actual implementation of `Register`. If it just adds callback to some event then making the method generic will remove the allocation to pass the struct (though you still will need to allocate the delegate and closure, I assume)

Answer (score 1):

The key to avoiding boxing when using structs that implement interfaces is to use interface-constrained generics.

If one has a function that receives an argument of type `T`, where `T` is constrained to `IEquatable<T>`, then the .NET runtime will generate a separate machine code version of that function for every distinct structure type that is passed to it, and within those machine-code versions of the function no boxing will be required.

Comment: Interesting! I'll have to look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a answer but just a suggestion . Decoupling `Data` and `Behaviour` , it's more clean design. and make sure Register param is a class. this way is good to handle boxing by you self. maybe use object pool or something. This way can handle unnecessary GC.

```
public class EventSystem
{
    // here make sure T is a class , not struct.
    public void Register<T>(T callbackStruct, Event e) where T : class , ICallback
    {
    }
}

public enum Event
{
    SOME_EVENT,
    SOME_OTHER_EVENT
}

public interface ICallback
{
    void Run(string data);
}

class Example
{
    private Behaviour_A a = new Behaviour_A();
    private Behaviour_B b = new Behaviour_B();

    public Example()
    {
        EventSystem eventSystem = new EventSystem();

        staticAObj.PutData(a);
        eventSystem.Register(staticAObj, Event.SOME_EVENT);
        eventSystem.Register(b, Event.SOME_OTHER_EVENT);
    }

    struct A
    {
    }
    struct B
    {
    }

    class Behaviour_A : ICallback
    {
        A a;
        public void Run(string data)
        {
            // some behvaiour
        }
    }

    class Behaviour_B : ICallback
    {
        B b;
        public void Run(string data)
        {
            // some other behvaiour
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed something obvious, your registration method should just add the `ref` modifier:

```
public void Register(ref ICallback callbackStruct, Event e);
```

This guarantees your structure will not be copied on the stack because only the reference will be copied, and your original struct can be used through that. The heap remains intact.

You will have to modify the callsite:

```cs
eventSystem.Register(ref a, SOME_EVENT);
eventSystem.Register(ref b, SOME_OTHER_EVENT);
```

And, based on Guru's comments, this might be a solution: further modify the signature to

```cs
void Register<T>(ref T callbackStruct, Event e) where T : ICallback;
```

or

```cs
void Register<T>(ref T callbackStruct, Event e) where T : struct, ICallback;
```

to remove the box, but you're possibly adding brittleness to this code.

For your`EventSystem` to register this it would need to be either non-abstract and provide the method below, or it would need a subclass that implements

```
public void Register<T>(ref T callbackStruct, Event e) where T : struct, ICallback
{}
```

Comment: Working with struct via interface will lead to boxing which OP explicitly wants to avoid.

Comment: Er. Yeah. So could we add a generic overload of `Register` to remove the box?

Comment: It depends on what the `Register` will actually do.

Comment: `<T>` <-- use that how regist all case ?

Comment: See my updated answer. At the callsite, you won't have to provide the `<T>` due to type inference.

Comment: my quesion is `List<T>.Add(callbackStruct)` <-- this how to register difference type of `T`
can you show `Register<T>` method practice ?

Comment: if event system want to call event , how to do it ?